# Finding the period for annuities

Tags: annuity

I've got a question relating to annuities which I'm stuck on.

You intend to retire when you are 60 and predict you will die when you are 90. You want 50,000 a year for a comfortable retirement, and you plan to get this money through an investment account. The account pays a return of 6%. On your 60th birthday, you will withdraw $50,000. You will continue to withdraw this amount until your 89th birthday. At that point there will be no money left in your account. How much money will you need to have saved from now until you are 60?

I understand the mathematics behind this, but what confuses me is that the instructor set n = 30 when doing the calculations. This is confusing to me - I understand that there are a total of 30 withdrawals but shouldn't n be 29 as there are 29 years from your 60th birthday until your 89th?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

No, it comes to 30:

```
~ R
> length(60:89)
[1] 30
```

Comment: How to do it without a computer: By subtracting 59 from 60 we obtain the "sequence number" 1. By subtracting the same 59 from 89 we obtain the sequence number 30. This shows that the years 60...89 have sequence numbers from 1 to 30. Therefore there are 30 of them.